# project.vim and commands using the shift key

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying to get up and running using project.vim but for some reason, none of the keybinding requiring a capital letter seem to be working.

For example `\C`, which should create new project fold recursively, just acts like normal C, but `\c` operates as expected. Same thing with `\R` and `\r`.

I'm using MacVim with Vim 7.3 (on a Mac, obviously). Is there some kind of keybinding voodoo that I need to implement first?

Thanks.

Comment: what does `:verb map <Leader>C` tell?

Comment: n  \C *@:call <SNR>52_CreateEntriesFromDir(1)<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/project.vim

Comment: @Bryan M. If you do `:normal \C<CR>`, does it work? If it does not, try to do `:debug normal \C<CR>s<CR><CR><CR><CR><CR>...` and see what happens.

Comment: @ZyX `:normal \C<CR>` does fire the command properly.

Comment: @Bryan M. Then maybe you are just not typing it fast enough? Try `set timeout timeoutlen=5000 ttimeoutlen=100` and type it again.

Comment: Bingo! Turns out some .vimrc settings I had copied from someone had dialed it down to 250! Thanks for restoring my sanity. If you want to credit, post that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `normal \C` works fine, the problem must be with `timeoutlen` option (*The time in milliseconds that is waited for a key code or mapped key sequence to complete.*). To restore it to reasonable values, use

```
set timeout timeoutlen=5000 ttimeoutlen=100
```